# print("...") está sendo executado várias vezes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz um programa para verificar se o CPF informado é válido, mas está acontecendo um bug:

Quando digito um CPF válido imediatamente, a mensagem "O Cpf...." é impressa uma vez.

Quando digito um CPF errado e depois digito o válido, a mensagem "O Cpf...." é impressa duas vezes, e assim por diante: o número de vezes que é passado um CPF inválido é o número de vezes extras que é impresso o "O CPF: ....".

Não estou consiguindo entender o porquê disso.

Outra coisa: quando coloco um `print()` dentro de um `while`, o `print` é executado mais vezes do que o `while`: o `while` roda 3 vezes e o `print` é exibido 6 vezes.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse bug?

**O código:**

```
import os # Importando o Modulo Os -> Operating Systems

class ValidaCPF:

    CPF = "Vazio"

    def GetCPF(self):

        os.system("cls")

        print("--------Regras-------  ")
        print("| Apenas 11 Digitos |  ")
        print("| Apenas -- Numeros |  ")
        print("|___________________|  ")

        print("\n")

        self.CPF = input("Digite O CPF: ")

        self.Test1()

    def Test1(self):

        os.system("cls")

        if self.CPF.isdigit() != 1 or len(self.CPF) != 11: # ! O CPF INFORMATO CONTEM 11 DIGITOS?

            print("CPF Invalido.")
            os.system("pause")
            self.GetCPF()

        self.Test2()

    def Test2(self):

        Verifica1 = 0
        Contador1 = 0
        Contador2 = 1

        while Contador1 < 9:

            if self.CPF[Contador1] == self.CPF[Contador2]:
                Verifica1 += 1

            Contador1 += 1
            Contador2 += 1

        if Verifica1 >= 8: # CPF COM Padrao -> 111.111.111.11 e etc.. sao Invalidos

            print("CPF Invalido.")
            os.system("pause")
            self.GetCPF()

        self.VerificaDigito1()


    def VerificaDigito1(self):

        Test = 0
        Contador1 = 0
        Contador2 = 10

        while 1:

            Test = Test + (int(self.CPF[Contador1]) * Contador2)

            Contador1 += 1
            Contador2 -= 1

            if Contador2 == 1:
                break

        Test = Test * 10
        Test = Test % 11

        if Test == 10:
            Test = 0


        if Test != int(self.CPF[9]):

            print("CPF Invalido.")
            os.system("pause")
            self.GetCPF()

        self.VerificaDigito2()

    def VerificaDigito2(self):

        Test = 0
        Contador1 = 0
        Contador2 = 11

        while 1:

            Test = Test + (int(self.CPF[Contador1]) * Contador2)

            Contador1 += 1
            Contador2 -= 1

            if Contador2 == 1:
                break

        Test = Test * 10
        Test = Test % 11

        if Test != int(self.CPF[10]):

            print("CPF Invalido.")
            os.system("pause")
            self.GetCPF()

        print("O CPF: ", self.CPF, "E Valido.")

       Sistema = ValidaCPF() # <--- Error de indentação A partir daqui

       Sistema.GetCPF()      # <--- Retirar a Tabulação 

       os.system("pause")    # <--- ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos ver se consigo lhe ajudar. Começando dividindo a dúvida em duas:

1 - Quando digito um CPF errado e depois digito o válido, a mensagem "O Cpf...." é impressa duas vezes [...] .

```
  if Verifica1 >= 8: # CPF COM Padrao -> 111.111.111.11 e etc.. sao Invalidos

        print("CPF Invalido.")
        os.system("pause")
        self.GetCPF()
        sys.exit(0) <== Pelo que pesquisei, isso deve resolver
```

Quando você informa que o CPF é inválido e chama a funçaõ "getCPF" novamente, você não PARA a execução do primeira "validação do CPF". Após esse getCPF, procure dar um "parar" na execuçaõ. Por que analisando o código, ele está após processar o "self.getCPF()" continuando a execuçaõ, ou seja, indo para o "self.verificaDigito1()".

2 - A dúvida 2 tem relação com o "bug" da primeira. Quando ocorre a digitação de um CPF inválido, ele não PARA a execução.

Vou tentar deixar mais claro mostrando a execução abaixo:

**Considere que eu digitei um CPF inválido inicialmente:**

```
    if Verifica1 >= 8: # CPF COM Padrao -> 111.111.111.11 e etc.. sao Invalidos

        print("CPF Invalido.") <== Da o alerta
        os.system("pause") 
        self.GetCPF() <=== Pede o novo CPF !!

    self.VerificaDigito1() <== Mesmo eu digitando o CPF inválido, ele irá executar essa função depois de processar todo o "self.getCpf"
```

Comment: Vlw =) Coloquei um else depois de cada If resolveu

Comment: Que bom Vitor!! Fico feliz em ajudar.